# Sum of fields from separate tables

Tags: sql, join, sum

I have two tables.  Table A has 5 records, table B has 4 records.  My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    sum(labor), sum(setup), sum(actual)
FROM 
    TABLE A 
LEFT JOIN 
   TABLE B ON [TABLE A].OP = [TABLE B].OP
```

**TABLE A**

```
op | labor | setup
---+--   --+---
10 |  0.05 |  0
20 |  0.3  |  0.2
30 |  0.05 |  0
40 |  0.0  |  0
50 |  0.0  |  0
```

**TABLE B**

```
op | actual
---+----
10 |  0.05 
20 |  3.083
20 |  0.283
20 |  0.3
```

I need to do a sum of the labor, setup and actual, in one row. So labor = 0.4, setup = 0.2, and actual = 3.716. The problem I am having is I am getting labor = 1, setup = 0.6, and actual is 3.716 because TABLE B has 3 records with op 20.

I've also tried using over(partition by op) but I am getting the same result.  Can someone please help, I've been staring at the query for hours and beginning to lose my mind.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that aggregation on the second table before the `join`:

```
SELECT sum(labor), sum(setup), sum(actual)
FROM TABLE A LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT OP, SUM(actual) as actual
      FROM TABLE B
      GROUP BY OP
     ) b
     ON [TABLE A].OP = b.OP;
```

Otherwise, your rows multiply after the `join`, and the aggregation on the first table doesn't work.